# SQL30080N error points to two documents SC31-6160 and (SC31-6156

Tags: db2

If I face this problem: SQL1476N with sqlerror "-30080", then I check this other error:

```
db2 ? sql30080


SQL30080N  A communication error "<reason-code>" occurred sending or
      receiving data from the remote database.
...
Refer to the document IBM Communications Manager 1.0 APPC Programming
Guide and Reference (SC31-6160) for explanation of the APPC primary and
secondary return codes. For details of APPC sense data, refer to the IBM
Communications Manager 1.0 Problem Determination Guide (SC31-6156).
```

When can I get information about these documents?

- IBM Communications Manager 1.0 APPC Programming Guide and Reference (SC31-6160).
- IBM Communications Manager 1.0 Problem Determination Guide (SC31-6156)

Reference:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/sql28000-sql33999.html#sql30080n

Comment: In what situation do you get the error, when you try to set up federation or when you use it?

Comment: Yes, this happens when using federation. Any idea? About the documents, what are those documents?